# Flutter Firestore, How to add list of objects in array

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to add list of objects in firestore as shown in the images. i could only add two list with the below code

```
 onPressed: () {
        _fireStore.collection('notifyseller').document().updateData({
          'Customer': userName,
          "address": controller.text,
          "mobile": mobileNumber,
          "Item": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
            {
              "name": itemName.toList()[0],
              "price": rate.toList()[0],
              "quantity": quantity.toList()[0]
            },
           {
              "name": itemName.toList()[1],
              "price": rate.toList()[1],
              "quantity": quantity.toList()[1]
            },
          ]),
        });
      },
```

here itemName.toList() contains list of strings. by the above code i can only add two data. i need to add all the item in the itemName.toList() to that array, instead of giving index for each array

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure that your three list have same length try this;

```
List yourItemList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++)
  yourItemList.add({
    "name": itemName.toList()[i],
    "price": rate.toList()[i],
    "quantity": quantity.toList()[i]
  });

_fireStore.collection('notifyseller').document().updateData({
  'Customer': userName,
  "address": controller.text,
  "mobile": mobileNumber,
  "Item": FieldValue.arrayUnion(yourItemList),
});
```

Comment: bro that worked; but is there any simple way like with forEach or map functions; here i need to change my stateless to stateful widget to call that for loop in initstate

Comment: because of using different lists it's difficult to use map or foreach methods in your case.

Comment: Do you have any idea to retrieve this

Answer (score 2):

i did this way

```
class Item{
String name;
String price;
String qty;

//named constructor here

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'price': price,
      'qty':qty,
    };
  }
}
```

```
List<Items> items = [Item(name:"",price:"",qty:""),Item(name:"",price:"",qty:"")]
    
_fireStore.collection('notifyseller').document().updateData({
  'Customer': userName,
  "address": controller.text,
  "mobile": mobileNumber,
  "Item":, items.map<Map>((e)=> e.toMap()).toList();
});
```